# Преобразование случайной величины с равномерным распределением в величину с нормальным распределением

Tags: c++, математика, теория-вероятностей

У меня есть некое кол-во случайных величин float в диапазоне [0;1] и эти величины имеют равномерное распределение.

Если такая величина X имеет нормальное распределение, то, величина
K = m + a * tan(PI*(X-0.5)) имеет распределение коши.

Возможно ли по аналогии преобразовать такую величину X, в величину имеющую нормальное распределение?

Comment: [Преобразование_Бокса_—_Мюллера](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Преобразование_Бокса_—_Мюллера)

Comment: Функция есть, но нужно вручную дописать обратную функцию к `Erf`. `Result[x=(0 .. 1)]:=Medium+Sqrt[2]*Sigma*InverseErf[2*x-1]`

Comment: [Центральная предельная теорема](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Написал грубо и точно (2.5%) функцию **InverseErf**. Она очень сложна для вычислений.

```
// g++ inverf.cpp -o inverf
# include <math.h>
# include <iostream>

// -1 => -Inf ; 0 => 0 ; +1 => Inf
// -0.82 .. +0.82 => третья степень
// 0.82 .. 1.0 => сложно
double InverseErf(double x){
  bool flagneg = (x < 0.0);
  x=fabs(x);
  double result;
  if(x<0.82) result = (x*x*0.37+0.88)*x;
  else {
    x=log(1.0-x);
    double const HalfPi = 1.57 ;
    result = sqrt(-x-log(-HalfPi*(log(HalfPi)+2.0*x))/2.0);}
  return flagneg ? -result : result ; }

double SimpleToNormal(double x , double med , double sigma){
      return med + sqrt(2.0)*sigma*InverseErf(2.0*x-1.0);}

int main() {
      std::cout<<"inverf(0.999)="<<InverseErf(0.999)<<std::endl;
      std::cout<<"inverf(0.99)="<<InverseErf(0.99)<<std::endl;
      std::cout<<"inverf(0.9)="<<InverseErf(0.9)<<std::endl;
      std::cout<<"inverf(0.75)="<<InverseErf(0.75)<<std::endl;
      double med = 0.0;
      double sig = 1.0;
      std::cout<<"0.999: "<<SimpleToNormal(0.999,med,sig)<<std::endl;
      std::cout<<"0.99: "<<SimpleToNormal(0.99,med,sig)<<std::endl;
      std::cout<<"0.9: "<<SimpleToNormal(0.9,med,sig)<<std::endl;
      std::cout<<"0.75: "<<SimpleToNormal(0.75,med,sig)<<std::endl; }
```

Метод Мюллера спровоцировал на ещё один красивый вариант (не точный) формулы **InverseErf**:

```
double InverseErf(double x){
  double result = sqrt(-log(1.0-x*x))*0.9;
  return (x < 0.0) ? -result : result ; }
```

Comment: Метод Мюллера спровоцировал на ещё один красивый вариант формулы InverseErf.