# Как сгенерировать случайные числа со среднеквадратичным отклонением?

Tags: математика, теория-вероятностей

Как сгенерировать случайные числа с заданным математическим ожиданием и **среднеквадратичным** отклонением?

Я знаю, как сгенерировать со средним отклонением, но не со среднеквадратичным.

Comment: а как вы генерируете со средним отклонением?

Comment: Генерируете случайное от -1 до 1. А потом `InverseErf`. Написан здесь : https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/855592/Преобразование-случайной-величины-с-равномерным-распределением-в-величину-с-норм/855655#855655

Comment: Форула здесь : https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Функция_ошибок

Answer (score 2):

Например, использовать генератор с [гауссовым распределением](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5), который имеется в библиотеках многих языков (randg,
std::normal_distribution,
numpy.random.normal и т.п.).

Заданная ему сигма - как раз нужное СКО (см. справа в таблице дисперсию)